# How to get values from a document based on a reference in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections in Firestore, `contacts` and `techs`, one of the contacts value is a reference to one of the techs documents, I am setting this reference using the path `collection name + id`, which I get after fetching `techs`:

`db.doc('techs/'+iconId)`

As can be seen it works:

[image]

I can retrieve it without any problems:

```
const getContacts = () => {
    return db.collection('contacts').get()
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async e => {
    const querySnapshot = await getContacts()

    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log('Reference value')
        console.log(doc.data().icon)
        console.log('Reference path')
        console.log(doc.data().icon.path)
    })
})
```

[image]

But I couldn't find a way to use this reference to actually get the value it is pointing to in `techs` collection.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `icon` field is actually a `DocumentReference` itself, so you can call `get()` on it to retrieve the document that it refers to.

Answer (score 1):

You can't unfortunately. You will have to write another query that takes the part of the string value that is the document id in the techs collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
const getTechs = (Id) => {
     db.collection('techs').doc(id).get().then(res=>{
     console.log(res.data())  
})
}


const getContacts = () => {
    return db.collection('contacts').get()
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async e => {
    const querySnapshot = await getContacts()

    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log('Reference value')
        console.log(doc.data().icon)
        console.log('Reference path')
        console.log(doc.data().icon.path)
        const path = doc.data().icon.path
        const id = path.split('/').pop()
        getTechs(id)
    })
})
```